# FB.ui is giving me Error Message: redirect_uri is not owned by the application

Tags: facebook

Help please! I'm creating a Facebook tab/app on facebook for a contest, part of the contest is to have a user have the option to share the contest on their wall. This is the error I'm receiving -

API Error Code: 191
API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
Error Message: redirect_uri is not owned by the application.

This is my facebook auth code:

```
<div id='fb-root'></div>
<script>
      FB.init( {
    appId  : 219691398094935,
            status : true, 
            cookie : true, 
            xfbml  : true
        }
        );
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.Canvas.setAutoResize();
        }
        </script>
<script src='http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js'></script>
```

This is my FB.ui Code:

```
 <script>
                function showStreamPublish() {
                FB.ui(
                   {
                     method: 'feed',
                     name: 'I signed up to win an iPad 2 from Upillar.com',
                     link: 'http://www.facebook.com/pages/udev/121216321302968?sk=app_219691398094935',
                     picture: 'http://static.upillar.com/fb/images/logo.png',
                     description: 'I entered the iPad 2 Sweepstakes from Upillar.com which only requires you to create a listing to enter! Enter the contest now by by clicking this link.',
                     app_id: '219691398094935'
                   },
                   function(response) {
                         if (response && response.post_id) {
                             $('#main-screen').css('display','none');
                             $('#step2').css('display','block');
                         }else{
                            $('#main-screen').css('display','none');
                            $('#step2').css('display','block');
                         } 
                    });}
                    </script>
```

This is the information in my app:
Site/App Domain: upillar.com
Site URL: `http://fb.upillar.com/contest.php`
Page Tab URL: http://fb.upillar.com/contest.php
Secure Tab URL: https://fb.upillar.com/contest.php

Please tell me what am I missing! Thank you so much.

Comment: Try using / at the end of your URLs

Comment: Usman, thank you for your response, I tried that with both forms http://fb.upillar.com/ and http://upillar.com/ and I still get the error.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I think you have to set `redirect_uri` to https://apps.facebook.com/yourapp . I don't know how to do it with JS SDK. In PHP SDK I set with `getLoginUrl` .

Answer (score 1):

Got same problem - solution is simple, but not even mentioned by Facebook Dev DOCS. Take a look at this:

```
FB.ui(
    {
        method: 'feed',
        redirect_uri: 'http://www.yourdomain.com', // that caused the problem
        message: 'getting educated about Facebook Connect',
        name: 'Connect',
        caption: 'The Facebook Connect JavaScript SDK',
        description: (
            'A small JavaScript library that allows you to harness ' +
            'the power of Facebook, bringing the user\'s identity, ' +
            'social graph and distribution power to your site.'
        ),
        link: 'http://www.yourdomain.com',
        picture: 'http://www.yourdomain.com/f8.jpg',
        actions: [{
            name: 'yourdomain',
            link: 'http://www.yourdomain.com'
        }],
        user_message_prompt: 'Share your thoughts about RELL'
    },
    function (response) {
        if (response && response.post_id) {
            alert('Post was published.');
        } else {
            alert('Post was not published.');
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer a bit more? I'm having this same problem, and it is clearly related to the redirect_uri parameter, but I'm not clear whether your code is the right or wrong way. In other words, when your code says `//that caused the problem` what does that mean?

Comment: There is nothing in FB docs that even mentions about 'redirect_uri' parameter, but in some cases it must be included. This parameter must be same as in Facebook application configuration.

Comment: Indeed. The FB docs suck! What I have learned (through trial-and-error) is that parameter can be omitted entirely in this case. That's why the error message is extremely misleading. When the parameter is included, it cause the dialogue not to close properly. Urgh.

Answer (score 0):

site URL should not be a file, try to set this as your domain only, without contest.php

if that does not work, set the canvas URL as your domain, with "/" at the end too.

Comment: I tried using http://fb.upillar.com/ as my Site URL, then http://upillar.com/ as my Site URL and got nothing.

In addition to those attempts I also added the same URL to my Canvas URL. For instance, 

Site URL: http://fb.upillar.com/
Canvas URL: http://fb.upillar.com/

And I still received an error.

Comment: I tried the same thing, shortening the Site URL, and it didn't help for me either.  :(

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to bump an old post, first I should say i'm relatively new to facebook development but i've been getting the same problem, basically it seems like facebook does some fairly nifty detection in terms of what qualifies as a redirect when you land on your page.

For example I was detecting if it was a new user and then displaying a colorbox, whose onclick event redirected to a newuser creation form. That gave me error 191 redirect_uri not owned. It seems because the javascript was in the `<HEAD>` element it qualified as a redirect.

I simply changed the login process to fully render the main page and display a normal div telling them to click here to login.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for grave-digging!
I just had the same problem and found the solution. You do not have to change anything on your sources.

Just head over to http://developers.facebook.com open your app and navigate to "Settings" and "Basic".

There is a textfield that says "App Domains" - enter the domain name where the app is currently hosted at there, save the settings and you are done.